# SharePoint Designer workflow replaces special characters from Rich Text Field with garbage

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, rte

We are trying to build a very simple workflow so blog post users can email their posts to specific users/groups.  The workflow should be pretty simple, just grabbing the body from the list item and inserting it into an Email action using CurrentItem:Body (value returned as String). (To and Subject lines are populated as well)

The problem we have is that special characters from the RTE are being replaced in the email.  For Example:

`&#160;` => `B`

`’` => `bEM`

`•` => `b"`

The Outgoing E-Mail Settings character set is 65001 (Unicode UTF-8)

I tried using http://spdwfstringactions.codeplex.com to remove the most common offenders before the workflow sends out the email, but I found that the transformation had already occurred. (Doing a find and replace on 'B' isn't practical)

Is there another way to retrieve the list item that won't garble the field contents?

I'd prefer not to do such a simple workflow in Visual Studio but that may be the only solution.

Comment: Rewrote the workflow using Visual Studio and the character replacement no longer occurs.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a rendering problem. Please see if Kevin Talbot's response on [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/7f66abe2-7890-479b-b38b-349d3d1937d5) helps you at all.

Comment: Question: is all HTML being incorrectly parsed, or only certain special characters? Are URLs and images etc. displaying correctly?

Comment: URLs, images, etc are all working, just certain special characters get garbled.  The page renders perfectly in the browser, it is only when going through a SPD workflow that there is trouble.